# Definir un arreglo con valores por defecto en PHP

Tags: php

Hay alguna forma simplificada de definir un arreglo y colocarle valores por defecto? Por ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```
$arrData = [];
for($i=0; $i<20; ++$i) $arrData[] = 0;
```

Alguna idea? Sé que en Java y C++ se puede pero en PHP desconozco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tu necesitas es la función [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-fill.php) o puede que prefieras [`array_fill_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-fill-keys.php). Cada una de estas funciones devuelven un array, al igual que la función `Array()`, sólo que en vez de, explícitamente, brindar un valor a cada elemento, brindas (ademas del valor que quieres que se repita en todos sus elementos) la cantidad de elementos (y su índice inicial) para `array_fill()` o la colección de índices para `array_fill_keys()`.

Tu ejemplo se traduciría de la siguiente manera:

```
$arrData = array_fill(0, 20, 0);
// Digase: (Indice inicial, cantidad de elementos, valor de dichos elementos)
```

Te dejo los enlaces para que mires mejor la documentación, pero y cito a `array_fill()`:

> Llena un array con `$num` entradas del valor del parámetro `$value`, las keys inician en el parámetro `$start_index`.

Sintaxis:

> `array array_fill ( int $start_index , int $num , mixed $value )`

También, si quisieras "suplantar" todos los valores de un array existente por un valor único, el uso de `array_fill_keys()` entra en acción de la siguiente manera:

```
$arrData = array_fill_keys(array_keys($arrData), 1);
// Digase: (arreglo de indices, valor para dichos indices)
```

En este caso usé la función [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys.php) para devolverme un arreglo de los indices actuales de un array existente. En este caso el array existente era `$arrData`, y por tanto me devolvió un array con sus mismos índices pero cargados con el valor `1` en todos ellos, este array lo guardo en `$arrData` y por tanto digo que "suplanto" sus valores existentes (aunque no sea estrictamente cierto).

Comment: No conocía de esa función, me parece la más correcta para el OP.

Comment: @Kleith Sinceramente me la enseño Google hace una hora, la que conocía era Array_Keys. Me alegro que ambos hayamos aprendido algo nuevo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Kleith es exactamente lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Así ibas medio bien

```
$arrData = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < 20; $i++ ){
 $arrData[] = $i;
 //Tambien puedes usar $arrData[$i] = $i;
}
var_dump( $arrData );
```

Solo te faltó declarar la variable como arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera usando `array_push`, este hace que se inserte uno o mas elemento al final del array.

```
$arrData = array();
for($i=0; $i<20; $i++)
{
    array_push($arrData,$i);
}

print_r($arrData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, PHP es muy flexible y hace parte del trabajo por nosotros si lo dejamos.

Para incializar un arreglo vacío:

```
$arr = [];
//O también puedes
$arr = array();
```

Una forma para llenarlo sería algo como:

```
$arr[] = "perro";
$arr[] = "gato";
$arr[] = "pato";
```

Aquí PHP hace la magia de asignarle el valor a la casilla siguiente, es decir, sería lo mismo hacer:

```
$arr[0] = "perro";
$arr[1] = "gato";
$arr[2] = "pato";
```

Para objetos más complejos puedes usar la siguiente estructura:

```
$arr = [
    "foo" => "pato",
    "bar" => "perro",
];
```

También puedes inicializar el arreglo de forma simultanea de esta forma:

```
$arr=array(10,20,30,40,50);
```

Y ya de ahi puedes hacer cosas locas como JSON o estructuras complejas:

```
$arr=array(6,"santosh","rahul",array("x","y","z"));
```

Para que tengas en cuenta, la versión de PHP que estes utilizando hace que puedas usar unas u otras formas, en especial Antes y Después de la 5.4. Todos los ejemplos que te di son para versiones posteriores a esta.

Por último, un [link](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.array.php) para consultar las diferentes funciones que puedes aplicar a los arreglos en PHP, siempre cuidando la versión que estes usando.